# Left join query issue

Tags: sql, ms-access

Can you let me know where I am facing syntax error in this query...the query contains three tables and all are joined together using left join.Plz provide a solution...

```
select a.ACNo as CLIENTACCOUNTNO,
b.CLIentSHoRTCoDE as CLIENTCODE,
a.Client as CLIENTNAME,
a.SECURITY_TYPE as  SECURITYTYPE,
c.SECMSECNO as  SCRIPCODE,
a.EXCE as  EXCH,
a.SEC_IDENT as  SECIDENT,
a.SECURITY_NAME as  SECURITYNAME,
a.INST_TYPE as  INSTTYPE,
a.SECURITY_CCY as  SECURITYCC,
a.SECURITY_PRICE as  SECURITYPRICE,
a.PRICE_DATE as  PRICEDATE,
a.LOCATION as  LOCATION,
a.LOCATION_STATUS as  LOCATIONSTATUS,
a.HOLDINGS as  HOLDINGS,
a.UNITS as  UNITS,
a.SALEABLE_STOCK as  SALEABLESTOCK,
a.FACE_VALUE as  FACEVALUE,
a.CCY_PORTFOLIO_VALUE as  CCYPORTFOLIOVALUE,
a.PORTFOLIO_VALUE_ININR as  PORTFOLIOVALUE,
a.MATURITY_DATE as  MATURITYDATE,
a.PREV_COUPON_DATE as  PREVCOUPONDATE,
a.NEXT_COUPON_DATE as  NEXTCOUPONDATE,
a.OPTION_DATE as OPTIONDATE,
a.DEADLINE_DATE as  DEADLINEDATE,
a.EVENT_TYPE as  EVENTTYPE
from CRS_BCP_Holding as a left join
AccountMaster as b on Cint(a.acno) =b.CashAcNo left join InstrumentMaster as c on
a.SEC_IDENT=c.ISIN and c.status<>'c' and c.bse_Code='b'
where ((a.OPTION_DATE between 8/04/2013 and 8/04/2013 ) and (a.LOCATION_STATUS='Surrendered for CA' OR a.EVENT_TYPE='PART'))
order by b.CLIentSHoRTCoDE,c.SECMSECNO,a.LOCATION,a.LOCATION_STATUS
```

[image: ScreenShot]

This query is used in access 2007

Comment: surround your date with # and try to execute your query. Can you also elaborate what error message are you getting.

Comment: The bit of SQL reported in Access' error message is different than the code you posted. It's missing `AS` between `InstrumentMaster` and `c`...

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Get rid of `as a` in `from CRS_BCP_Holding as a left join`:</strike> (sorry, I misread the query. `AS a` is fine, with the caveat described further below.)

```
(...)
FROM CRS_BCP_Holding AS a
     LEFT JOIN AccountMaster AS b
            ON CInt(a.acno) = b.CashAcNo
     LEFT JOIN InstrumentMaster as c
            ON (...)
```

Also, if you really need to use abbreviations, I’d use ones that make a tad more sense (such as 'cbh' for 'CRS_BCP_Holding', and 'am' for 'AccountMaster', etc.) Using 'a', 'b', 'c' for any tables makes it very hard to read what a column refers to.

Also, like Santosh says in his comment, VBA uses hashes to specify a date literal:

```
 WHERE ((a.OPTION_DATE BETWEEN #2013-04-08# and #2013-04-08#) ...)
```

(I've also formatted the date using the ISO standard date format, to make sure the date is interpreted correctly, regardless of the system's locale.  On my (Dutch) machine, 8/04/2013 is interpreted as '8 april 2013'; whereas on our US server, it will be interpreted as 'August 4th, 2013'. 2013-04-08, on the other hand, is unambiguous.

Taking everything together, does the following work?

```sql
  SELECT a.acno AS clientaccountno
  ,      b.clientshortcode AS clientcode
  ,      a.client AS clientname
  ,      a.security_type AS securitytype
  ,      c.secmsecno AS scripcode
  ,      a.exce AS exch
  ,      a.sec_ident AS secident
  ,      a.security_name AS securityname
  ,      a.inst_type AS insttype
  ,      a.security_ccy AS securitycc
  ,      a.security_price AS securityprice
  ,      a.price_date AS pricedate
  ,      a.location AS location
  ,      a.location_status AS locationstatus
  ,      a.holdings AS holdings
  ,      a.units AS units
  ,      a.saleable_stock AS saleablestock
  ,      a.face_value AS facevalue
  ,      a.ccy_portfolio_value AS ccyportfoliovalue
  ,      a.portfolio_value_ininr AS portfoliovalue
  ,      a.maturity_date AS maturitydate
  ,      a.prev_coupon_date AS prevcoupondate
  ,      a.next_coupon_date AS nextcoupondate
  ,      a.option_date AS optiondate
  ,      a.deadline_date AS deadlinedate
  ,      a.event_type AS eventtype
    FROM crs_bcp_holding AS a 
         LEFT JOIN AccountMaster AS b 
                ON CInt(a.acno) = b.cashacno
         LEFT JOIN InstrumentMaster AS c
                ON a.sec_ident = c.isin
               AND c.status <> 'c'
               AND c.bse_Code = 'b'
   WHERE (a.option_date BETWEEN #2013-04-08# AND #2013-04-08#) 
     AND  (a.location_status = 'Surrendered for CA' OR a.event_type = 'PART')
ORDER BY b.clientshortcode
,        c.secmsecno
,        a.location
,        a.location_status
```

Comment: @user2230817: What happens if you do `a.acno = b.CashAcNo` instead of `CInt(a.acno) = b.CashAcNo`?

Comment: @Martijin thnks for ur quick rply...a.acno datatype is text whereas b.CashAcno is in number...so Cint is used to convert the text into integer.

Comment: @user2230817: that's obvious (BTW, it's very bad practice to join a text and a numeric column; I suggest you change the table definition). But you didn't answer my question: what happens if you omit the `CInt`?

Comment: The problem I am facing is of syntax....and if I remove CInt it would show me an error of datatype...I cannot change the datatype as its already is in use...